# OSGI embedded classes not resolving

Tags: java, osgi, rhino, aem, sling

We are using Day cq. It uses Apache Felix osgi container. In one of our projects we are using Rhino for serverside scripting. Day already comes with Rhino library included as part of org.apache.sling.scripting.javascript - here Rhino library is part of this Sling bundle, not an embedded jar, and it is a bit older version.

We want to use latest version of Rhino library so we added it as part of our bundles libs section, but we are not able to access the latest jar. Rather we still have access to the old version.

How can we override this?

Comment: And did you make the Rhino bundle available to the container, e.g. by appropriately installing it? What are the bundle dependencies listed by the other bundles in the application?

Comment: sorry if i am not clear, i embedded rhino-1.7R4.jar in test.jar osgi bundle, rhino-1.7R4.jar is not an osgi bundle, I am able to compile test.jar osgi bundle with embedded rhino-1.7R4.jar and installed in felix and it is in active state, my test bundle is very simple and no external dependencies, i have access to rhino api which is part of org.apache.sling.scripting.javascript osgi bundle which is bit old but not to the one i embedded in my test.jar , so what i want is to use rhino-1.7R4.jar which i included as part of my test.jar osgi bundle, how can i override this please help.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want an "OSGi version" of the Rhino library.  Based on a quick search, I found the following possibilities.

- https://github.com/KnisterPeter/OSGi-Rhino
- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.matrixweb.osgi.wrapped/osgi-wrapped-rhino/1.7R4

The primary service of the above examples is to provide the OSGi manifest to Felix.  Alternately, you can provide your own manifest.

Comment: Thanks @IT Gumby, I thought i could override existing osgi rhino version with my embedded jar version but it is not working, as you said i deployed latest OSGI version of the rhino instead of embedded version now it is working as expected.